# FB Messenger bot integrated with wit.ai does not work as in test mode

Tags: facebook, wit.ai

I have integrated wit.ai with FB Messenger, but the results I get while talking to him via Messenger are not the same I get while talking to him in testing mode. Specifically the variables are not populated in the bot response. Although they are well populated when I test the bot in test mode within wit.ai site.

I have attached 2 screenshots as you can see the **{contact}** variable (in this case 'Nick') is not added in the response text. Can you please suggest why is this happening? As I assume the communication between Messenger and wit.ai is pure text, and there should not be any other handling on the Messenger side (for example manually populating the variables).

[Testing bot from wit.ai Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNgIL.png)

[Messenger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1NaS.png)

Comment: Show us what you have done in Wit.ai (Stories)

Comment: Here is a screenshot from the wit.ai stories http://imgur.com/a/ptX9Y

Comment: I am testing right now and have same problem. In web console all is fine but responses for http requests (using curl) miss variables in "msg" every time.

Comment: Looks like a bug in wit.ai ?

Comment: Actually you need an action on your side to check if you have a wit/contact entity at that point in the query and store it inside a context variable:
context.contact= contact_from_entity;
Example here: https://wit-ai.github.io/witty-fiddle/?id=5a387f6ccb4be4a1f77f2113747a558a